# The image within my custom UICollectionViewCell does not extend to the entire bounds of the cell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to laod an array of images to a collectionview that is within a UIViewController.  The UIImageView within my custom UICollectionViewCell is not extending to the bounds of the cell and I do not understand why.  Below is my code.

ViewController:

```
var dragCollectionView: UICollectionView!
var dragCollectionViewWidth: CGFloat!
let borderInset: CGFloat = 3
var interCellSpacing: CGFloat = 3
var spacingBetweenRows: CGFloat = 3

let container1: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    return v
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    view.addSubview(container1)
    container1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    container1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
    container1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    container1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    container1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor).isActive = true

    setUpCollectionViewForPuzzlePieces()  
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    print("")
    print("viewDidLayoutSubviews ...")

    dragCollectionViewWidth = dragCollectionView.frame.width

    dragCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dragCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container1.topAnchor).isActive = true
    dragCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container1.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    dragCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container1.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    dragCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container1.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    setupLayoutDragCollectionView()
}

private func setUpCollectionViewForPuzzlePieces(){
    let frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
    dragCollectionView = UICollectionView.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    dragCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    dragCollectionView.delegate = self
    dragCollectionView.dataSource = self

    container1.addSubview(dragCollectionView)
    dragCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dragCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container1.topAnchor).isActive = true
    dragCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container1.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    dragCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container1.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    dragCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container1.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    // Register UICollectionViewCell
    dragCollectionView.register(GirdyPickCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}

private func setupLayoutDragCollectionView(){
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = interCellSpacing
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = spacingBetweenRows
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: borderInset, left: borderInset, bottom: borderInset, right: borderInset)

    guard
        let collectionViewWidth = dragCollectionViewWidth,
        let numRows = numberOfGridColumns else{return}
    print("numRows: \(numRows)")


    let cellWidth = getCellWidth(numRows: numRows, collectionViewWidth: collectionViewWidth, interCellSpace: interCellSpacing, borderInset: borderInset)
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize.init(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)

    print("margins.layoutFrame.width: \(margins.layoutFrame.width)")
    print("collectionViewWidth: \(collectionViewWidth)")
    print("cellWidth: \(cellWidth)")
    print("")
}


private func getCellWidth(numRows: CGFloat, collectionViewWidth: CGFloat, interCellSpace: CGFloat, borderInset: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{

    let numSpacing = numRows - 1
    let cellWidth = (collectionViewWidth - interCellSpace * numSpacing - borderInset * 2) / numRows
    return cellWidth
}


extension StartGameViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let data = puzzlePieces else {return 0}
        return data.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = dragCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! GirdyPickCollectionCell
        guard let data = puzzlePieces else {return cell}
        cell.imageView.image = data[indexPath.row].image
        return cell
    }
}
```

My custom UICollectionViewCell:

```
class GirdyPickCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var image: UIImage?
    var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imgView = UIImageView()
        return imgView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.addSubview(imageView)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        setUpLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setUpLayout(){
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.height).isActive = true
    }  
}
```

CONSOLE:

```
viewDidLayoutSubviews ...
numRows: 5.0
margins.layoutFrame.width: 343.0
collectionViewWidth: 100.0
cellWidth: 16.4


viewDidLayoutSubviews ...
numRows: 5.0
margins.layoutFrame.width: 343.0
collectionViewWidth: 343.0
cellWidth: 65.0
```

What I am currently getting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in your view controller and provide the size in `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                            layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                            sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let kWhateverHeightYouWant = 100
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat(kWhateverHeightYouWant))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add constraints to Left (or leading), Top, Right (or trailing) and bottom of the imageView.
This will also help you to set padding between the frames if required.

Use this code:

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set all edges constraints instead of giving width and height,
Try to add constraints like this

```
private func setUpLayout(){
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```